# How to drag the screen and snap to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I'll explain what I mean in more detail**:
There is a way to make the entire screen movable by either dragging it with the cursor, or touching it with your fingers. You're then in turn able to snap to the div closest to your location. The div is also able to adjust based on resolution and changing the screen size.
Here is the prime example: http://making.gene.com/1/start/

I'm interested in how you can accomplish this, and I've done research on the subject.
There are many jquery plugins that let you snap to a div, or move an object on the screen, but nothing to the degree i'm looking for.

This is my first post, so let me know if there is something I can add that will help you.

Here is an example of snapping to a div, the most i've been able to find out.

```
<script src="src/jquery.scrollsnap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scrollsnap({
        snaps: '.snap',
        proximity: 50
    });
});
</script>
```

This lets you snap to a div when you scroll near it, while also being able to change the proximity of when it snaps.

Comment: Good explanation but what approach has yet been made? Try something out and come back with some code examples. Specific problems is encouraged!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, added more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/

this plugin snap the section

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/path/to/jquery.panelSnap.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function($) {
        $('body').panelSnap();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      ...
    </section>
    <section>
      ...
    </section>
    <section>
      ...
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic example, thank you! I'd up vote you if I could. Happy to see all the help i'm getting from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you should start from here

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

working demo: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ and  http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm going to try and merge some sort of dragging function with the snap divs. The logic actually doesn't seem too bad to accomplish.